# My UIWebView is reloading lazily. How can I make it reload / refresh when I want the data to be displayed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to get a UIWebView to update dynamically, sort of like a karaoke box, as it iterates through a while loop. The word that the tts engine is speaking should be in orange (or in html, .style2).

What is happening, however, is that the UIWebView doesn't update its display through each iteration of the htmlKaraoke string, but only the last one in the while loop. UIWebView appears to be reloading in a lazy way, and waiting until the while loop is finished before updating it's display. I've included in my code all the different ways I've tried to circumvent this (setNeedsDisplay, setNeedsLayout, reseting the htmlKaraoke string, reloading the UIWebView) but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

The html code is updating like it should (with the spoken word in orange), but the webview isn't reflecting this.

**How can I get the webView to update after every update of the htmlKaraoke string?**

```
i = 0;
NSString *htmlHead              = @"<html><head><style type='text/css'><!-- .style1 { font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica; } .style2 {color: #FF9900} --> </style></head><body><span class='style1'>";
NSString *htmlFoot              = @"</span></body></html>";
NSString *htmlEmpHead           = @"<span class='style2'>";
NSString *htmlEmpFoot           = @"</span>";
NSMutableString *htmlKaraoke = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

while(i <= wordWeAreUpToInt){
    //wait until the tts is finished talking.
    if(![[fliteEngine audioPlayer] isPlaying]){
        //NSLog(@"flite is finished!");

        //Add the word and highlight in the karaoke

            /*  Clear the html string
                Make a for loop, where n = 0, n<i, n++
                    append black word
                when for loop ends, and n == i, add an emph word (n==i when i is the currently spoken word). 
             */
        [karaokeWebView loadHTMLString:@" " baseURL:nil];
        [karaokeWebView reload]; //doesn't do anything. These two lines are a waste of breath. 

        [htmlKaraoke setString:htmlHead];
        for (int n = 0; n<i; n++) {
            [htmlKaraoke appendString:[wordsArray objectAtIndex:n]];
            [htmlKaraoke appendString:@" "];
        }
        [htmlKaraoke appendString:htmlEmpHead];
        [htmlKaraoke appendString:[wordsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [htmlKaraoke appendString:@" "];
        [htmlKaraoke appendString:htmlEmpFoot];
        NSLog(@"Emphasis: %@", [wordsArray objectAtIndex:i]);           
        [htmlKaraoke appendString:htmlFoot];


        NSLog(@"htmlKaraoke: %@", htmlKaraoke);

        [karaokeWebView loadHTMLString:htmlKaraoke baseURL:nil];
        [karaokeWebView setNeedsDisplay];
        [karaokeWebView setNeedsLayout]; //getting desperate....!

        //speak the word
        [self readSentence:[wordsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        i++;
    }
}

[htmlKaraoke release];
wordWeAreUpToInt++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that UIWebView only renders the view *after* control returns back to the main NSRunLoop / Event Loop. So, if you're making all of your updates within the while loop above, then only the last string is getting loaded as it never got the chance to load the other ones (& so will just use the last load request).

You will need to return out of any code you've written (not just this method, but also whatever triggered this being called, etc.) and return control back to the OS, before the UIWebView will update with your changes.

Assuming that whatever object this code is in is still around after control returns, you could test this out by adding this to your class:

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string {
    [karaokeWebView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
}
```

And then change your `-[loadHTMLString:baseURL:]` calls into:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadHTMLString:) withObject:htmlKaraoke afterDelay:_delay_increasing_by_a_second_for_each_string];
```

There's more on the main "Event Loop" in the "[Application Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17)" section of the "iOS Application Programming Guide".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can anyone think of another way to animate/ achieve this? This action is the result of clicking a button.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Give the sample test code in there a shot. For animating though the strings, you'd just increase the delay slightly for each (so the first one is at 1 second, then two seconds, then three, etc.).

Comment: Oh, and note that you'll likely need to pass in a _copy_ of the string at each point, otherwise you'll just be passing a pointer to the mutable string (which you change as the loop goes on). Do this by changing the `withObject:htmlKaraoke` bit.

Comment: Pretty ingenious answer, and certainly worth its upvotes. It's just not practical though - I can't, no matter how long I try, get the timing right for the animation. Plus there's the complication of how different words take a different amount of time to say - which throws the animation out a bit more.

Comment: I went back and had a look and got it working by using the duration property in the audio player (this is a FliteEngine property) and using the performSelector withDelay on *both* loadHTMLString: and readSentence:. The delay was figured out with the sum of the previous words' duration + a constant for space between words (0.1).